# Laravel Bulk Update via a array request

Tags: laravel, eloquent, laravel-8, laravel-query-builder

| id | incharge_id | member_id | project_id |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | 3 | 1 | 1 |
| 2 | 3 | 4 | 1 |
| 3 | 3 | 2 | 1 |
| 4 | 3 | 6 | 1 |
| 5 | 5 | 2 | 2 |
| 6 | 5 | 4 | 2 |

I am working with update on above table `projectmembers`.
`$request->member_id` returns an array that contains few user_ids like [1,4,2,6]

> I have to update the member_id's of specific project_id

```
foreach ($request->member_id as $item => $value) {
    DB::table('projectmembers')
        ->where('project_id', $id)
        ->update([
            'member_id' => $request->member_id[$item]['member_id']
        ]);
}
```

in some cases a project_id can have 3 members / 5 members it depends on the request we get from `$request->member_id`. what is the best way to update the member_ids on table

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Next solution is to update your table in 2 steps.

1. delete data on the basis on `project_id`
2. And prepare array with `request->member_id` and `project_id` for insertion.

Lets suppose we have `project_id` and `incharge_id` in request.
let's take example below.

```
TableName::where('project_id', $project_id)->delete();

$array = array();
foreach ($request->member_id as $key => $val) {
    $array[] = [
        'member_id' => $val['member_id'],
        'project_id' => $project_id,
        'incharge_id' => $incharge_id
    ];
}

TableName::insert($array);
```

You can update your table in 2 queries instead of 5 queries.